# Cmd-clicking on the names of sh/md files in iTerm2 opens them in the browser (non-deterministically)

Tags: iterm

I am using macOS Sonoma 14.1.2 with iTerm2. I often search for files in the terminal, which then I would like to open by Cmd+clicking on their name. This should open them in the default text editor.

However, I noticed that certain file formats, such as Markdown (`.md`) and Shell (`.sh`), are sometimes picked up as URLs and are opened in my default brower. To reproduce, run:

```
cd /tmp
touch hello.md world.sh
echo hello.md world.sh
```

The when clicking on the printed `hello.md` and `world.sh` strings, the result is either opening the browser (to load `https://hello.md/` or `https://world.sh/`), or it is opening the respective files in the default text editor. The exact choice is non-determistic.

Is there a way to disable interpreting these filenames as URLs?